# Do any nonconstant analytic functions have at least one fixed point $L$ such that $\frac{\ln(f'(L))}{2\pi{i}}\notin\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose $f$ is a nonconstant analytic function, a point $L$ is said to be a fixed point if $f(L)=L$, we call the value $\lambda=f'(L)$ "multiplier". (By minimum modulus principle applied to $f(z)-z$, $L$ must exist.)

If the limit $\lim_{z\to{e^{i\beta}}\infty}f'(z)$(in a specific direction) exists and $\lim_{z\to{e^{i\beta}}\infty}f(z)-z=0$ we call the point at infinity also a fixed point of f. For instance, $f(z)=z+e^z$ has a fixed point at $-\infty$.

It's essential in dynamic systems whether $$\frac{\ln(\lambda)}{2\pi{i}}\notin\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}.$$
If this holds, the dynamic systems have a continuous flow, otherwise it's ultra-difficult to gnerate such flow, even can be impossible.
(Such fixed point is called constructable.)

So it's crucial to ask whether any analytic function has at least one fixed point $L$ satisfying $\frac{\ln(f'(L))}{2\pi{i}}\notin\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$, allowing anyone to build up a complex continuous flow?

**The linear case $f(z)=az+b$ is not in discussion.**

**Any functions $g$ conjugate to the linear case $f$** (for a function $g$ there exists an analytic(can be multivalued) function $\phi$ that $\phi\circ{g}\circ\phi^{-1}=f$) **are not in discussion.**
For instance, functions $2z\sqrt{1-z^2},\frac{az+b}{cz+d},az^r$ are conjugate to a linear case, hence they have closed-form flows, so we're not interested in these cases.

What we already know:

1. A quadratic function $f(z)=az^2+bz+c$ always have at least one constructable fixed point. This can be proved simply through Vieta's theorem.
2. Any polynomial functions having no multiple fixed points (or all fixed points are distinct) always have at least one constructable fixed point, proved by contradiction if assumed it has no such fixed points.

Comment: Well, some functions have no fixed points at all (take $f(z)=e^{g(z)}+z$ for any analytic $g$).

Comment: If you are talking about holomorphic functions $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\to\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ then the only such functions are rational functions.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you for your recomment, the question is modified.

Comment: Emm... then why function $f(z)=z+e^z$ is not $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\to\hat{\mathbb{C}}$? idk how to describe this constriction rigorously lol

Comment: $f(z)=z+e^z$ does not approach any limit at $\infty$.  (It has an essential singularity there.)

Comment: Oh I see, the terms are wrong. Thx